# Can I refresh all the Word Document metadata using DocumentFormat.OpenXml

Tags: ms-word, openxml-sdk

I have an application that uses the DocumentFormat.OpenXml API to a Word document from one or more originating documents, inserting and deleting chunks of data as it goes.  In other words, the resulting document will be significantly different from the constituent documents.

I have already successfully created things like Custom Document Properties, Document Variables and Core File Properties.

But: is it possible to get the other metadata items (number of pages, words, paragraphs, etc.) refreshed, without actually having to calculate these?

Comment: Only by opening the document in the Word application or in Word Automation Services.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @Cindy Meister for the answer.

I was hoping that there might be some method or other in the DocumentFormat.OpenXML SDK that I could call, but it seems that is not possible.